# zend framework 3 session not working

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I'm trying to set up a zend framework 3 MVC web app to use session storage.  Following the information from this website --

https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Working_with_Sessions/PHP_Sessions.html

It all works well.  I get the session variable in my controller and I can save data to the session container just fine.  The problem is, the data I save to the container is NOT there on subsequent calls.  I'm saving search criteria from one page and doing a redirect to a second page to do the search and return the results.  The session data is not present when I enter the second page.

In config\global.php I have --

```
return [
    'session_config' => [
        // Cookie expires in 1 hour
        'cookie_lifetime' => 60*60*1,
        // Stored on server for 30 days
        'gc_maxlifetime' => 60*60*24*30,
        ],
    'session_manager' => [
        'validators' => [
            RemoteAddr::class,
            HttpUserAgent::class,
            ],
        ],
    'session_storage' => [
        'type' => SessionArrayStorage::class,
    ],
];
```

In application\module.php i have modified onBoostrap

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $application = $event->getApplication();
    $svcMgr = $application->getServiceManager();

    //  Instantiate the session manager and
    //  make it the default one
    //
    $sessionManager = $svcMgr->get(SessionManager::class);
 }
```

I created an IndexControllerFactory

```
class IndexControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container,
                             $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        // Get access to session data
        //
        $sessionContainer = $container->get('Books\Session');
        return new IndexController($sessionContainer);
    }
}
```

Modified my IndexController to add a constructor method

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(Container $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }
```

In application\module.config.php i have this

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\IndexController::class => Controller\Factory\IndexControllerFactory::class,
    ],
],
'session_containers' => [
    'Books\Session'
],
```

Answer (score 4):

To store something in session you can create the container as follows:

```
// Create a session container
$container = new Container('Books\Session');
$container->key = $value;
```

To retrieve something from a session container later you have to create a new container with the same name:

```
// Retrieve from session container
$container = new Container('Books\Session');
$value = $container->key;
```

As far as I know this works similarly for both ZF2 and ZF3 and can be found in [other posts on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032226/sessions-in-zf2) or for example [this blog post with the title **Using Sessions in Zend Framework 2**](http://codingexplained.com/coding/php/zend-framework/using-sessions-in-zend-framework-2) .

If you create a new `Container` for storing or resolving data from the session it will automatically use the default session manager if you don't pass one yourself.

You can see that [here in the `AbstractContainer::__construct` method on line 77](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-session/blob/master/src/AbstractContainer.php#L77). If the `$manager` passed to the constructor is `null` it will get the default session manager inside [the `setManager` method](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-session/blob/master/src/AbstractContainer.php#L130-L150).

So to use sessions you don't need to do a lot of manual configuration.

If that doesn't solve your problem please leave a comment.